# Is the localized module of derivations the module of derivations of the localized algebra?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $X$ be an affine algebraic variety and $A=\mathbb{C}[X]$ its coordinate ring. The vector space
$$ \mathrm{Der}_{\mathbb{C}}(A) = \{ D: A \rightarrow A \mid D \text{ is linear and } D(ab)=D(a)b+aD(b) \ \forall a,b \in A \} $$ is an $A$-module. Let $S$ be a multiplicative closed set on $A$, then we may consider the $S^{-1}A$-module $S^{-1} \mathrm{Der}_{\mathbb{C}} (A) $.

> Is it true that $S^{-1}\mathrm{Der}_{\mathbb{C}}(A) \cong \mathrm{Der}_{\mathbb{C}}(S^{-1} A)$?

If yes, how do I prove it? Furthermore, is it true for other associative algebras?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your narrow question is yes.
The slightly longer answer is that, for any commutative ring $k$ and *finitely presented* commutative $k$-algebra $A$, $S^{-1} \textrm{Der}_k (A) \cong \textrm{Der}_k (S^{-1} A)$.
The question doesn't make sense if $A$ is non-commutative: in that case $\textrm{Der}_k (A)$ has no obvious $A$-module structure so what would $S^{-1} \textrm{Der}_k (A)$ even be?

We could prove the claim directly, but it is somewhat tedious because the universal property of $S^{-1} A$ is with respect to $A$-linear maps or ring homomorphisms but derivations are neither.
It is more convenient to use a different perspective here.

**Definition.**
Given a ring $A$ and an $A$-bimodule $M$, the **Beck module** $A \oplus M \epsilon$ is the ring defined as follows:

- The elements are the formal sums $a + m \epsilon$, where $a \in A$, $m \in M$, and $\epsilon$ is a formal symbol.
- $0$, $1$, and $+$ are defined in the obvious way.
- Multiplication is defined by the following formula:
  $$(a_0 + m_0 \epsilon) (a_1 + m_1 \epsilon) = a_0 a_1 + (m_0 a_1) \epsilon + (a_0 m_1) \epsilon$$

There is an obvious ring embedding $A \to A \oplus M \epsilon$, sending each $a$ to $a + 0 \epsilon$, and there is also a surjective ring homomorphism $A \oplus M \epsilon \to A$ sending each $a + m \epsilon$ to $a$.
However, there can be many other ring embeddings $A \to A \oplus M \epsilon$, not necessarily sending $a$ to $a + 0 \epsilon$.
Indeed:

**Proposition.**
Let $k$ be a commutative ring, let $A$ be a $k$-algebra, let $M$ be an $A$-bimodule, and let $D : A \to M$ be a $k$-linear map.
The following are equivalent:

1. The map $\phi_D : A \to A \oplus M \epsilon$ defined by $\phi_D (a) = a + D (a) \epsilon$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism.
2. $D : A \to M$ is a derivation, i.e. $D (a_0 a_1) = D (a_0) a_1 + a_0 D (a_1)$ for all $a_0$ and $a_1$ in $A$.

*Proof.*
Suppose $\phi_D$ as defined is a $k$-algebra homomorphism.
Then,
$$\phi_D (a_0 a_1) = \phi_D (a_0) \phi_D (a_1) = a_0 a_1 + D (a_0) a_1 \epsilon + a_0 D (a_1) \epsilon$$
but $\phi_D (a_0 a_1) = a_0 a_1 + D (a_0 a_1) \epsilon$ as well, hence $D$ is indeed a derivation.

Conversely, if $D$ is a derivation then reversing the above argument shows $\phi_D$ preserves multiplication.
It is clear that $\phi_D$ is $k$-linear and preserves $1$, so we indeed have a $k$-algebra homomorphism.　◼

In other words:

**Corollary.**
Let $k$ be a commutative ring, let $A$ be a $k$-algebra, and let $M$ be an $A$-bimodule.
There is a natural bijection between the set of $k$-linear derivations $A \to M$ and the set of $k$-algebra homomorphisms $\phi : A \to A \oplus M \epsilon$ such that $\pi \circ \phi = \textrm{id}_A$, where $\pi : A \oplus M \epsilon \to A$ is the $k$-algebra homomorphism defined by $\pi (a + m \epsilon) = a$.　◼

From here on, $A$ will be commutative and $A$-bimodules will be symmetric (i.e. $a m = m a$).
Note that $A \oplus M \epsilon$ is then also commutative, and the $k$-module $\textrm{Der}_k (A, M)$ of $k$-linear derivations $A \to M$ has an induced $A$-module structure.

**Proposition.**
Let $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$.
The restriction operation $\textrm{Der}_k (S^{-1} A, S^{-1} M) \to \textrm{Der}_k (A, S^{-1} M)$ is bijective, i.e. for every $k$-linear derivation $D : A \to S^{-1} M$ there is a unique $k$-linear derivation $\tilde{D} : S^{-1} A \to S^{-1} M$ such that $\tilde{D} \left( \frac{a}{1} \right) = D (a)$.

*Proof.*
Suppose given a $k$-linear derivation $D : A \to S^{-1} M$.
Let $\phi_D : A \to S^{-1} A \oplus S^{-1} M \epsilon$ be the map defined by $\phi_D (a) = \frac{a}{1} + D (a) \epsilon$.
It is straightforward to verify that $\phi_D$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism.
Furthermore, if $s \in S$, then $\phi_D (s)$ is a unit in $S^{-1} A \oplus S^{-1} M \epsilon$: indeed,
$$\left( \frac{s}{1} + D (s) \epsilon \right) \left( \frac{1}{s} - \frac{1}{s^2} D (s) \epsilon \right) = \frac{1}{1} + 0 \epsilon$$
so there is a unique $k$-algebra homomorphism $\tilde{\phi} : S^{-1} A \to S^{-1} A \oplus S^{-1} M \epsilon$ such that $\tilde{\phi} \left( \frac{a}{1} \right) = \phi_D (a)$ for all $a \in A$.
We have $\pi \circ \tilde{\phi} = \textrm{id}_{S^{-1} A}$, hence $\tilde{\phi}$ corresponds to a $k$-linear derivation $\tilde{D} : S^{-1} A \to S^{-1} M$ such that $\tilde{\phi} \left( \frac{a}{s} \right) = \frac{a}{s} + \tilde{D} \left( \frac{a}{s} \right)$.
It is clear that $\tilde{D} \left( \frac{a}{1} \right) = D (a)$, and it is straightforward to check that the construction $D \mapsto \tilde{D}$ defined here is the required two-sided inverse for the restriction operation.　◼

**Proposition.**
There is a well-defined map $S^{-1} \textrm{Der}_k (A, M) \to \textrm{Der}_k (A, S^{-1} M)$ sending each formal fraction $\frac{D}{s}$ to the derivation $a \mapsto \frac{D (a)}{s}$, and it is bijective if $A$ is finitely presented.

*Proof.*
There is an obvious $A$-linear map $\textrm{Der}_k (A, M) \to \textrm{Der}_k (A, S^{-1} M)$ induced by the natural map $M \to S^{-1} M$.
Since $S$ acts invertibly on $\textrm{Der}_k (A, S^{-1} M)$, this immediately extends to an $S^{-1} A$-linear map $S^{-1} \textrm{Der}_k (A, M) \to \textrm{Der}_k (A, S^{-1} M)$, and it is easy to check that it is the map in the proposition.

It remains to be shown that the map is bijective if $A$ is finitely presented.
There is an abstract nonsense proof, which basically amounts to observing that $S^{-1} M$ is a colimit of a filtered diagram that $\textrm{Der}_k (A, -)$ maps to the diagram whose colimit defines $S^{-1} \textrm{Der}_k (A, M)$, and when $A$ is finitely presented then $\textrm{Der}_k (A, -)$ preserves filtered colimits, so we are done.
Spelling all this out concretely gives a direct proof: essentially, given a $k$-linear derivation $D : A \to S^{-1} M$ and a finite presentation of $A$, we can find some $s \in S$ that is "big" enough so that there is a well-defined map $A \to M$ defined on the generators by $a \mapsto s D (a)$.
($s$ needs to be "big" enough not just to clear the denominator of $D (a)$ for each generator $a$, it also needs to annihilate all the relations between the chosen generators!)　◼

**Corollary.**
If $A$ is a finitely presented commutative $k$-algebra and $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$, then $S^{-1} \textrm{Der}_k (A) \cong \textrm{Der}_k (S^{-1} A)$.　◼

---

Since there seem to be doubts about whether a finiteness hypothesis is required, here is a counterexample.
Let $A = k [s, t_0, t_1, t_2, \ldots]$ and let $S = \{ 1, s, s^2, \ldots \}$.
There is a unique $k$-algebra homomorphism $A \to S^{-1} A \oplus S^{-1} A \epsilon$ sending $s$ to $s$ and each $t_n$ to $t_n + \frac{t_n}{s^n} \epsilon$.
This extends to a $k$-algebra homomorphism $S^{-1} A \to S^{-1} A \oplus S^{-1} A \epsilon$, so we get a $k$-linear derivation $D : S^{-1} A \to S^{-1} A$.
It has the property that (even after reducing fractions to lowest terms) there is no constant $N$ such that $s^N D (a) \in A$ for all $a \in A$.
Hence, there is no $k$-linear derivation $\tilde{D} : A \to A$ such that $D = \frac{1}{s^N} \tilde{D}$ for some $N$, demonstrating the non-surjectivity of $S^{-1} \textrm{Der}_k (A) \to \textrm{Der}_k (S^{-1} A)$.

Comment: Are you sure the finite presentation hypothesis is necessary?  Exercise 21.2.L in [Vakil](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) says it's true in general.

Comment: That’s a different claim. It translates to the second proposition above, which indeed holds without a finiteness hypothesis.

Comment: @RaviFernando I added a counterexample.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I misread the question.  +1

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you give me a reference for the "abstract nonsense proof" for that part of the last proposition?

Comment: Not really. If you want to learn about presentability in abstract categories then you can read e.g. _Locally presentable and accessible categories_ but I don't recall seeing this application.